# Lightweight pluggable Java RIA framework

Tags: java, frameworks

I'm looking for a lightweight, no bells and whistles framework built in JAVA for the web, which would allow me to build plugins around it.

Ideally, I'd like to include features such as:
- LDAP integration
- User level access control

Any suggestions?

Many thanks, 
Vlad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're building your Web application on top of the Java EE Platform, then you could use JAAS which come with LDAP support, AFAIK.